# LINQ Inner Join on Substring with length of left side

Tags: c#, linq

We are pulling data from two databases and creating a list of an object from each of those. Pretend we have QueryOne and QueryTwo .. QueryOne returns only 8 characters of the transaction id for one row, but the next row it is of length 10. QueryTwo has a transaction id of length 25. We need to join on a substring of QueryTwo transaction id of the length of QueryOne's trans id. Please note, I know this is not always going to join reliably.

```
var foo = from x in queryOne 
        join y in queryTwo on x.TransId equals y.TransId.Substring(0, x.TransId.Length) 
        select new {x , y};
```

In this example code, x is not in scope on the y side of the equals. Is there another way to do this with LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could get the same result without `inner join` :

```
var foo = from x in queryOne
          from y in queryTwo
          where x.TransId == y.TransId.Substring(0, x.TransId.Length)
          select new { x, y }
```

OR

```
var foo = from x in queryOne
          from y in queryTwo
          where y.TransId.StartsWith(x.TransId)
          select new { x, y };
```